# Android: How to give Height and width to gif image in picasso

Tags: android, height, width, picasso

Hi I'm using the picasso for loading gif image (I'm loading this gif image just before loading the actual image or error in the image URL)

**Code:**

/res/drawable/progress_animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progress_image"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />
```

---

```
Picasso.with(context).load("google.com").error(R.drawable.progress_animation).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation).into(holder.imageURL);
```

Used image
[image]

For this code, I want to give height and width to gif image. Can any one help to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.resize(width, height)`, example:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("google.com").error(R.drawable.progress_animation).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation).resize(30, 30).into(holder.imageURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the method of resize().

```
Picasso.with(context).load("google.com").resize(50, 50).error(R.drawable.progress_animation).placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation).into(holder.imageURL);
```